# file input multiple file selection not working

Tags: php, laravel

when i die/dump $files i can only see one file in the request when am expecting to see all the files selected. when i die/dump $name in the foreach loop nothing is happening. I need to see all the selected images in the request.

### blade create

```
<form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" files = "true"> 
@csrf
<label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __(' post image') }}</label>

                        <input type="file", class="form-control-file" id ="image" multiple = "multiple" name="image">
                        @error('image')
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong> </div>
                                
                            @enderror
 
</form>
```

### postcontroller

```
 public function store( Request $request )
{` $request->request->add(['user_id' => $user],  ); // Here a request is given a varible either for the admin or user
    $data = request()->validate([
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'about' => 'required',
        'category' => '',
        'expire_date' => '',
        

    ]); `if (Auth::guard('web')->check())
     {
       $user = Auth::user();
       $post = new Post();

       /*$post = $user->posts()->create([
            'about' => $data['about'],
            'category' => $data['category'],
            'expire_date' => $data['expire_date'],
            
        ]);*/
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
          $files = $request->file('image');
          
          
          foreach($files as $file)
          {
            
            $name = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $name = str_replace('','-',$name);
            
            $file->move('images',$name);
            
            //$post->images->create(['image' => $name ]);

          }
        } `
        $user = Auth::guard('web')->id() ;

       // return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);

        
    }


  }
```

Comment: Change `name="image"` to `name="image[]"`

Comment: @STA thanks that was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple input, in your html you need to pass it as an **array** for the name attribute. Change `name="image"` to `name=image[]`, i.e :

```
<input type="text" name="image[]" />
```

This way php will receive an array of **image**'s.

Answer (score 0):

The $casts property on your model provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types. The $casts property should be an array where the key is the name of the attribute being cast and the value is the type you wish to cast the column to.

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
     protected $casts = [
         'image'  =>  'array',
     ];
 }
```